# image encryption using AES in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, encryption, cryptography

I encrypted image by using the AES algorithm and I got a result but I'm not sure if programming is true. i want help to check the code.

```
import numpy as np
import random
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome import Random
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('t.jpg',1)#read image
na = np.array(img)#conver it to array
x, y ,pp= img.shape[:3]#size of 3d
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blue= np.array(range(x*y), int).reshape((x, y))
enc_blue= np.array(range(x*y), int).reshape((x, y))
blue[:,:]=gray[:, :]
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv=b'0000000000000000'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
L2=[]
blue1 = np.array(range(x),int)
for i in range(x):
    blue1=blue[i,:].tolist()
    blue2=bytes(blue1)
    msg =  cipher.encrypt(blue2)
    for p in msg:
        L2 += [(p)]
    enc_blue[i,:]=L2[:]
    L2=[]
cv2.imwrite('enc_blue.jpg', enc_blue)
```

[plain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5WTC.jpg)
[cipher image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7jaO.jpg)

Comment: A simple, but effective way to check would be to decrypt the cipher image with the same key and iv and see if you get back the original image (well the blue one).

Comment: Hey chat bot, tell the people at codereview that we got a candidate here. Somebody check out if it is up to the right level, cause I have trouble reading the code.

Comment: go to code review website for these types of problems

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for review of working code.

Comment: how can i shared to code review website

Comment: The code review site said that the code may not be functional, so they refused it. The problem is that I don't exactly know what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure if it is correct or not. There is `blue1`, `blue2` and no protocol description or anything.