# Create jpg/png from encrypted image

Tags: image-processing, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I'd like to be able to convert/display an AES256 asymmetric encrypted image even if it appears to be garbage, I've read a number of things on SO that suggest removing the headers and then reattaching them afterward so even if looks nutty it still displays it.

The point of this is that I want to see if it's possible to perform image classification on an image dataset encrypted with a known public key. If I have a picture of a cat and I encrypt it with exactly the same key, then the result will generally be reproducible and result in an image that in some way equates to the original.

Excuse the lack of code, I didn't want to pollute the discussion with ideas that I was considering in order to get a proper critique from you lovely people- I would say I'm not an encryption expert hence my asking for advice here.

Comment: Just some notes. "asymmetric" encrypted won't work as asymmetric encryption is only good for small amount of data (so use symmetric encryption like AES). Second: Running an encryption e.g. AES in CBC mode with a **random initialization vector** will give a "random" output and will differ each time you run the encryption, so there is nothing like "reproducible".

Comment: Third: you can search for "ECB Penguin" and you will find examples for "poor" encryption - those examples run in AES ECB mode and strip off the header of a BMP image, e.g. (disclaimer it's in German, Java language, and I'm the author) http://javacrypto.bplaced.net/g01-ecb-pinguin/

Comment: Heya Michael, thanks for this - so the thing I wanted to test is it possible to do e2e encryption whilst still allowing for classification of obnoxious content, I've read various scientific papers on the subject, it would seem if you're aware of the key you could then encrypt each image using the same method.?

Comment: This is the "problem" with encrypted data, you cannot classify on the encrypted content if they are obnoxious or not. Everyone that knows the **secret key** (that's why it's named secret...) is been able to en- and decrypt.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong, I don't want to decrypt it, I want to display the encrypted version, I also want to encrypt other images in the same way. So it would seem that the IV and public key would be needed to perform the "same" encryption. My question was however how would you display encrypted images  in their encrypted form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options, but I suggest to follow the following guidelines:

- Encrypt the image data, and not the image file.
  In case the image is 100x100x3 bytes, encrypt the 30000 bytes (not the `img.jpg` file for example).
  (The down side is that metadata is not saved as part of the encrypt image).
- Use lossless image file format to store the encrypted image (PNG file format for example, and not JPEG format).
  Lossy format like JPEG is going to be irreversible.
- Set the resolution of the encrypted image to the same resolution as the input image.
  That way you don't need to store the image headers - the resolution is saved.
  You may need to add padding, so the size in bytes be a multiple of 32.

---

I hope you know Python...

Here is a Python code sample that demonstrates the encoding and decoding procedures:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240967/image-encryption-using-aes-in-python
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = b'0000000000000000'

# Read image to NumPy array - array shape is (300, 451, 3)
img = cv2.imread('chelsea.png')

# Pad zero rows in case number of bytes is not a multiple of 16 (just an example - there are many options for padding)
if img.size % 16 > 0:
    row = img.shape[0]
    pad = 16 - (row % 16)  # Number of rows to pad (4 rows)
    img = np.pad(img, ((0, pad), (0, 0), (0, 0)))  # Pad rows at the bottom  - new shape is (304, 451, 3) - 411312 bytes.
    img[-1, -1, 0] = pad  # Store the pad value in the last element

img_bytes = img.tobytes()  # Convert NumPy array to sequence of bytes (411312 bytes)
enc_img_bytes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).encrypt(img_bytes)  # Encrypt the array of bytes.

# Convert the encrypted buffer to NumPy array and reshape to the shape of the padded image (304, 451, 3)
enc_img = np.frombuffer(enc_img_bytes, np.uint8).reshape(img.shape)

# Save the image - Save in PNG format because PNG is lossless (JPEG format is not going to work).
cv2.imwrite('enctypted_chelsea.png', enc_img)



# Decrypt:
################################################################################
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = b'0000000000000000'

enc_img = cv2.imread('enctypted_chelsea.png')

dec_img_bytes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).decrypt(enc_img.tobytes())

dec_img = np.frombuffer(dec_img_bytes, np.uint8).reshape(enc_img.shape)  # The shape of the encrypted and decrypted image is the same (304, 451, 3)

pad = int(dec_img[-1, -1, 0])  # Get the stored padding value

dec_img = dec_img[0:-pad, :, :].copy()  # Remove the padding rows, new shape is (300, 451, 3)

# Show the decoded image
cv2.imshow('dec_img', dec_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Encrypted image:
[image]

Decrypted image:
[image]

---

Idea for identifying the encrypted image:

- Compute a hash of the encrypted image, and store it in your database, along the original image, the `key` and the `iv`.
- When you have the encrypted image, compute the hash, and search for it in your database.

Comment: Just 2 Cents from my side: using a Block cipher like AES in CBC modes requires a multiple of **16 bytes** - this is the AES blocksize. To identify any file - why shouldn't we calculate a hash of the complete file (taking just the image data would require a own function for each image format (e.g. JPG, BMP, PNG, TIFF...) ?

Comment: Nice work Rotem, thanks a lot, marked as correct.

Comment: no problems on the Python we use it for all the ML stuff anyway - just about to test out your code now, if this works it's going to be something rather special.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using an answer, although it's **not an answer** because I'd like to show two pictures to demonstrate.

Both pictures were taken from my blog entry http://javacrypto.bplaced.net/g01-ecb-pinguin/ (German language).

The first picture shows the Tuc penguin after encryption with AES in ECB mode:

[image: Tuc penguin after AES ECB encryption]

The form still persists, and you can "imagine" what animal is shown.

The second picture was encrypted with AES in CBC mode and the output is looking like garbage:

[image: Tuc penguin after AES CBC encryption]

The conclusion: if the picture was encrypted with a mode like CBC, CTR or GCM you will always get something like the second picture, even if you know the mode, key and initialization vector that was in use.

**A visual comparison will not work**, sorry.

To answer your question in comment "how would you display encrypted images in their encrypted form": you can't show them because usually a picture has a **header** that gets encrypted as well, so this information will be lost. The two "encrypted" pictures were created by stripping off the header before encryption, then the picture data gets encrypted, and the header is prepended.