# Extracting Image Data from PNG for OpenSSL ECB Encryption and Reassembly

Tags: encryption, png

I'm working with ECB mode encryption and I came across the famous Tux Penguin image in PNG format. I want to extract the raw image data (excluding metadata), encrypt it using OpenSSL, and reconstruct the PNG so that it visually matches an encrypted version of the image.

I've researched the PNG format, but I'm finding it complex. Could someone guide me on how to extract the image data from a PNG file, perform CBC encryption using OpenSSL, and then reconstruct the file to achieve a visual match with an encrypted image?

I have tried to use a tool like xxd to view file content, but was not successful.

Any insights or resources on PNG data extraction and image encryption would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

[image].
[image].

Comment: 1. You need a format where the pixels are directly accessible. PNG uses compression; lossless compression but compression none-the-less (there are non-compressed inflate blocks possible but you'd still have to deal with the meta data). 2. That image was created using ECB, not CBC.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks, I was actually talking about ECB (Electronic Code Book)

Comment: Your question covers the two large topics of image formats and cryptography and is far too broad for SO in its current form. It also lacks a direct programming reference (not even a language is tagged). An introduction to the PNG format can be found [here](https://medium.com/@duhroach/how-png-works-f1174e3cc7b7). An implementation will strongly depend on the language and library used, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060392/9014097) is an example for Python.

Comment: What the heck does "visually matches an encrypted version of the image" mean? What even is "an encrypted version of the image"? Encrypted data, regardless of what was encrypted, will look like noise redered as an image, or in any other form for that matter.

Comment: @MarkAdler No, with ECB if you encrypt specific repeating patterns then those patterns persist in some way or other, as identical blocks will encrypt to identical ciphertext blocks. However, the penguin image is mainly used to show how this kind of information can lead to leaking information about the plaintext. The penguin should contain raw image data for this to work. People end up thinking that encrypting any penguin image, sometimes including meta-data, will end up looking like that and of course it doesn't as the *blocks themselves* are still randomized.