# How to Encrypt PNG Files with Alpha/Transparent in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, encryption

So, I have the following sample Python code. The code will accept the PNG plaintext input and encrypt it into PNG ciphertext (Scrambled pixels) as the output.

But when I try to use PNG with transparency (alpha channel), it doesn't work. How to read 4 channels (rgba) and store them into a Nummpy Array, encrypt them and then decrypt them to get the original image?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240967/image-encryption-using-aes-in-python
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = b'0000000000000000'

# Read image to NumPy array - array shape is (300, 451, 3)
img = cv2.imread('chelsea.png')

# Pad zero rows in case number of bytes is not a multiple of 16 (just an example - there are many options for padding)
if img.size % 16 > 0:
    row = img.shape[0]
    pad = 16 - (row % 16)  # Number of rows to pad (4 rows)
    img = np.pad(img, ((0, pad), (0, 0), (0, 0)))  # Pad rows at the bottom  - new shape is (304, 451, 3) - 411312 bytes.
    img[-1, -1, 0] = pad  # Store the pad value in the last element

img_bytes = img.tobytes()  # Convert NumPy array to sequence of bytes (411312 bytes)
enc_img_bytes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).encrypt(img_bytes)  # Encrypt the array of bytes.

# Convert the encrypted buffer to NumPy array and reshape to the shape of the padded image (304, 451, 3)
enc_img = np.frombuffer(enc_img_bytes, np.uint8).reshape(img.shape)

# Save the image - Save in PNG format because PNG is lossless (JPEG format is not going to work).
cv2.imwrite('enctypted_chelsea.png', enc_img)



# Decrypt:
################################################################################
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = b'0000000000000000'

enc_img = cv2.imread('enctypted_chelsea.png')

dec_img_bytes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv).decrypt(enc_img.tobytes())

dec_img = np.frombuffer(dec_img_bytes, np.uint8).reshape(enc_img.shape)  # The shape of the encrypted and decrypted image is the same (304, 451, 3)

pad = int(dec_img[-1, -1, 0])  # Get the stored padding value

dec_img = dec_img[0:-pad, :, :].copy()  # Remove the padding rows, new shape is (300, 451, 3)

# Show the decoded image
cv2.imshow('dec_img', dec_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read RGBA images and 16-bit PNG images with **OpenCV**, you need to use:

```
im = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Try that, and then check that `im.shape` is `(h,w,4)`

Comment: In my original code I have also added the cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED parameter when read the original Plaintext. But, when decrypted the CipherText, i got error : 

<built-in method hex of bytes object at 0x0000018661794FC0>

Comment: Try it with an image whose dimensions are a clean multiple of 16 to see if your padding code is causing errors. Also check the number of bytes your pixels take up before and after encryption.

Comment: It has nothing to do with dimention, size or multiple of 16 (AES). Because im using another cipher in my case, which is still work if plaintext has 3 channel. But if im using 4 channel (transparent/alpha), this is where the problem comes from.

Comment: It's rather unhelpful to show code a different cipher and different parameters to `cv2.imread()` from those you are using!!!